# Does Iran violate the JCPOA by developing nuclear-powered warships?

Tags: iran, jcpoa

Iran, Angered Over Obama's Renewal of Sanctions, [says it will develop](http://www.independent.co.uk/news/world/middle-east/iran-nuclear-powered-war-ships-response-us-sanctions-a7471566.html) nuclear-powered warships

> *Iran's President Hassan Rouhani orders
>   nuclear-fuelled warships*

Is this a violation of JCPOA?

Answer (score 6):

Note: It is almost always a good idea to link to the source of the news, to better address the points noted there.

Technically, it does not violate the deal because the deal forbids Iran to enriching Uranium, not to develop power plants. The main way of ensuring that are the ongoing IAEA missions, that so far have raised no warning signs.

That said, experts seem to agree that:

- power plants for nuclear vessels needs a supply of Uranium enriched beyond what the JCPOA agreed to, even if way under the grade needed for weapon building. So basically, they are vowing to develop ships that, under JCPOA, they would be unable to provide fuel for.
- developing such ships is not an easy task, it is expensive and may take up to a decade. It does need not only of the ships themselves, but also of very specific port structures.
- from an strategic point of view it is a dead end. Nuclear powered vessels are used for ships that need long range, and the Iranian Navy lacks the capacity to supply and operate those ships, (very few countries do have that capability, see [Blue-water Navy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blue-water_navy)).

http://www.reuters.com/article/us-usa-iran-nuclear-deals-idUSKBN14212X

http://gulfnews.com/news/mena/iran/iran-eyes-nuclear-powered-ships-after-us-sanctions-move-1.1944609

It is not a nice gesture, but it can be understood as a reply to the US Senate resolution of 1, Dec (which, in turn, is not a nice gesture but does not violate the JCPOA, either). Similarly to the US Senate resolution, it allows Iran politicians to show off a hard stance to silence their critics, without actually committing them to violate the JCPOA or changing the *status quo*.

Comment: Great answer. There are only two countries which have nuclear warships in the world and I strongly doubt Iran has the technology and money to build it. Cost outweighs benefit. I think your last sentence provides the reason. Iran might be trying "to give some warnings to Trump".

Comment: @Rathony I might be wrong, but I read it more as a way to deflect internal critics by Iranian hardliners; after all there is actually very little that Iran can threaten the USA with (leaving the JCPOA will automatically kick in back the sanctions or even more, so it will be far worse for Iran than for the USA).

Comment: I agree with you. Iran has both internal and external forces to deal with. Not an easy position for the leadership.

Comment: Your first bullet contradicted by the second bullet. The deal expires in 10-15 years, so if developing nuclear navy would take so long, then JCPOA restrictions would no longer be in place by the time the fuel would be needed. Also, bullet #3 is valid but there are SOME advantages to nuclear powered vessels, even for non-blue-water Navy (granted, they are much smaller and probably not worth the investment). Real answer seems to be the last paragraph - it's more of a symbolic gesture.

Comment: @user4012 the answer is meant to review ALL the main issues in the info I found, not to support just only one narrative -I try to understand other people POVs and not to just dismiss what I do not like-. So, yes, the points are not coherent and they are not meant to be. Point 1 explains why some people can have legitimate issues with Iran announcement even if it does not violate the JCPOA, as it could signal a future attempt to break it. The other points show that, if those were Iran intentions, the less "profitable" way of violating the JCPOA would be through a nuclear vessel.

Comment: "...power plants for nuclear vessels needs a supply of Uranium enriched beyond what the JCPOA agreed to" I don't see how this can be the case, because a ship doesn't use anything close to 1 Gigawatt of power that a large powerplant uses. The fuel that Iran gets from Russia for it's Bushehr plant should be more than enough...

Comment: @CountIblis I am no nuclear scientist (not enough youtube tutorials :-D); that claim is taken from the reuters newspiece. If I had to guess (again, no nuclear scientist) I would think that a ship will need a different, more compact and lighter nuclear engine than the ones operating in powerplant. Of course, I am open to edits if a better source can be found.

Comment: @SJuan76 - The problem lies more with the question (it's kind of broad, and the topic is subject to vague interpretation) than with the answer. I was merely pointing out ways to improve the answer by adding the notes about contradictions, not really criticizing it. Having said that, technically speaking, announcing future intentions doesn't contradict the agreement, de-jure, even if it makes it clear Iran isn't serious about said agreement in spirit.